# Prove some identites.

Tags: calculus

Prove the following identity. I do not know where to start. Any help would be most welcome. Thank you very much.
$$
\int_0^1 \left[-\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}}\right]dx=\sum_{l=1}^\infty \binom{-1/2} {l} \frac{1}{l}
$$

$$
\int_0^1 \left[-\frac{1}{x^3}+ \frac{1}{x^3 \sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{2 x^2 \sqrt{1+x}}-\frac{1}{8 x  \sqrt{1+x}} \right]dx=\sum_{l=3}^\infty\binom{-1/2}{l} \frac{1}{l-2}
    +\ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +\frac{1}{2} \sum_{l=2}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{l} \frac{1}{l-1}
    - \frac{1}{8}\sum_{l=1}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{l} \frac{1}{l}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right hand side of your first identity is nothing else than the **integral** of $\dfrac1x$ times the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) expansion for $(1+x)^{^{-\frac12}}=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x}}$ calculated at $x=1$. A similar approach applies to the right hand side of your other identity as well.

---

$$\int_0^1\left[-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}}\right]dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}-1\right]dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\left[\sum_{l=0}^\infty{-\frac12\choose l}x^l-1\right]dx=$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\left[1+\sum_{l=1}^\infty{-\frac12\choose l}x^l-1\right]dx=\sum_{l=1}^\infty{-\frac12\choose l}\int_0^1x^{l-1}dx=\sum_{l=1}^\infty{-\frac12\choose l}\frac{x^l}l|_0^1=$$

$$=\sum_{l=1}^\infty{-\frac12\choose l}\frac1l$$

Comment: I could see some calculations please? I'm sorry but I do not understand.

Comment: @Mark: Done! :-)